# Active Directory Authentication in .NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working on an intranet application which consists of a .NET Core Web API back end and a completely separate AngularJS SPA that queries it. A requirement of the project is authentication via AD (LDAP possible.) However, after studying for a while, I cannot seem to find a way for my backend API to receive a username/password and ask AD if it's correct, and what groups they are in, then store that locally and hand off a token to the SPA to use in future requests. Any ideas would be appreciated, thank you.

Note: The web app hands the password to the API in an encrypted format, the API decrypts it, and thats where I'm at.

Comment: The only out of the box authentication for this is IIS+Windows Authentication (you see it as option when creating a new ASP.NET Core project). It's not the same as you describe though, the currently logged in users authentication information is sent on each request to an enabled service. However, by default Firefox doesn't do that and you need to toy with its options to allow it. There is no on premise AD auth middleware (and no plans to add such one for security reasons), just AzureAD which is something different though